# Extreme sequence topology as coproduct

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let $X$ be the set of sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms and metric
$$
d(x,y)\triangleq \begin{cases}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |x_n-y_n| : &  x_n \neq 0 \,\, \text{iff} \,\, y_n\neq 0\\
\infty :& \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Is $X$ homeomorphic to $\coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $d$ is not a "real" metric, as $\infty$ is a value, but it induces a valid topology. And $B_d(\underline{0},1)$ in $(X,d)$ is strongly infinite dimensional (homeomorphic to $\ell^1$, really), while the coproduct is just one-dimensional, so they're not homeomorphic.

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu just basic dimension theory. Read the classics.

Comment: If I quotient $\coprod_n \mathbb{R}$ by identifying the point $1$ would that make a difference?

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu No since that would make $\coprod_n \mathbb{R}$ connected; whereas your other space is disconnected.

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu the coproduct is disconnected, so quotienting is no option.